# Facebook Audience Network.no fill rate. Test ads are working. Real ads are not working

Tags: facebook, flutter

I am getting zero fill rate for native and native banner ads. I tested with more than 30k ad-request but didn't get any fill rate at all. It keeps showing it is requesting ads but they are not getting filled even though the integration is correct.

The demo ads are working perfectly but when I change it to my placement ID, I get no fill rate. I have checked the integration thoroughly many time and there is no problem with the integration at all.

https://github.com/dreamsoftin/facebook_audience_network is the plugin I'm using. I checked if my placement ids are working using a native android app also, but I keep getting the same no fill rate

I checked solutions for this, I added the Network Security Configuration file, tested with the Device ID and test users from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing/ but nothing is solving the problem at all. I asked another who also came to the same conclusion that this is some server side issue.

image: https://ibb.co/Dthh8Vv

this is the message I get on the console log:

```
{error_message: No fill, invalidated: true, error_code: 1001, placement_id: 383262725809870_384038435732299}
```

I am sure that there is no integration error because the demo ads are working perfectly but the real ads are not getting filled. Can you please help me in this regards?

Also, can someone share any working banner, naative placement ids if you are okay?

Answer (score 0):

I am too facing this issue. This happened only on one app. I guess it might be account issue. Test devices added in facebook shows ads but no fill in all other devices. I did facebook with admob mediation.
The support at facebook is of no use. I suggest you try with a fresh account.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.